# String having a text part and number part separated through match function does not increment number part by 1 after 8

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the following code the value of newId is the SLP000001. This code adds increment to the value every time it runs. for example the next value after running the code would be SLP000002 and so on. Issue is that after running the code when value reaches at SLP000008 it starts again from SLP000001. I want to continue it to SLP000009, 10, 11, 12 and so on. please guide. I am new to appscript coding

```
  function myFunction() {
    var newId = sheet1.getRange(sheet1.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var splitting = newId.match(/[a-z]+|[^a-z]+/gi);
    var firstPart = splitting[0];
    var secondPart = splitting[1] ;
    var increment = parseInt(secondPart)+1;
    var combined = firstPart+"00000"+increment; 

 }
```

Comment: Can you share your increment block code here.

Comment: Where is the AppScript?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] otherwise nobody will be able to answer your question. Thank you.

Comment: Cleaned up the grammar and formatting. Was hoping the AppScript was hidden because he did something wrong with pasting his code, but it is not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP reports that `parseInt('00008');` returns 0 (zero) instead of decimal 8 (eight). The reason is that the leading zeros are causing `parseInt` to assume base 8 (instead of base 10).

**Solution**:
`var increment = parseInt(secondPart, 10)+1;`

**Explanation**

`parseInt` accepts two parameters:
 - a string (in this case, 'secondPart')
 - radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).
The Mozilla javascript documentation for [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) says *...always specify a radix when using parseInt.*

**Proof**:
 - `var oldparsed = parseInt('00008');` returns 0 (zero)
 - `var newparsed = parseInt('00008', 8);` returns 0 (zero)
 - `var parsedplus = parseInt('00008', 8)+1;` returns 1(one)
whereas
 - `var oldparsed = parseInt('00008');` returns 0 (zero)
 - `var newparsed = parseInt('00008', 10);` returns 8 (eight)
 - `var parsedplus = parseInt('00008', 10)+1;` returns 9 (nine)

Comment: Thank you very much Tedinoz. I was really disappointed by the response of previous people that was very discouraging. You helped me out of this. Thank you very much